# Duplicating Zoom CSS property on the same element resets zoom to 1 in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, zooming

Here is a simplified version of an issue (bug?) I experienced:

http://jsfiddle.net/LxkA2/8/

Notice the third element and associated styling:

```
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

In Chrome, this *resets* the zoom to 1 on that element. The same thing happens with:

```
.zoom-twice-same, .zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

However,

```
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 3;
}
```

Works as expected (element 2).

Furthermore,

```
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2.000001;
}

.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

Works as expected. Using `zoom: 2.0000001` and `2` does not.

Is this a bug or is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Nice find.. that's really strange. You would think the properties would overwrite each other. It's safe to assume this is a Chrome rendering bug..

Comment: @JoshCrozier That's what I figured. I submitted a bug report through Chrome. I guess it's not a huge bug but it can be a pain when dealing with some libraries that result in overlapping CSS (in my case, angular animate).

Answer (score 0):

I checked your JSFiddle and noticed you had the following CSS repeated twice:

```
.zoom-twice-same {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

When I removed the second `.zoom-twice-same` the problem didn't reoccur as you'll see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LxkA2/10/).

Comment: Right... my jsfiddle was specifically pointing out that duplicate CSS zoom definitions resulted in zoom not being applied at all.